# Bokeh: ColumnDataSource not rendering on Vbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

Trying to read the following into a vbar bokeh chart but it's not rendering anything beyond a blank figure.

```
Index | Sub Call Type      | Calls   |Total AHT
0     | Standard Checklist | 33111   |00:07:27
1     | About FSS          | 9447    |00:04:40
```

Trying to go with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

data = pd.read_csv("Desktop/Graph.csv")

output_file("bar_pandas.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(plot_height=350,title="Business Heatmap FYTD")

p.vbar(x="Sub Call Type",top="Calls",width=0.5,source=source)

show(p)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to specify that the data is [categorical](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html). This can be done with `x_range=list(catagories)`

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Sub Call Type": ["Standard Checklist", "About FFS"], "Calls": [33111, 9447], "Total AHT": ["00:07:27", "00:04:40"]})

output_file("bar_pandas.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(plot_height=350,title="Business Heatmap FYTD", x_range=data["Sub Call Type"])

p.vbar(x="Sub Call Type",top="Calls",width=0.5,source=source)

show(p)
```